# Show data in a-b format in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I have a table which has distinct numbers i.e int data type. Now I need a query which shows data in increasing order in the format `cast(a as varchar)+'-'cast(b as varchar)` i.e `a-b` where `a` is the smallest number which has yet not been shown and `b` is subsequently the next smallest number.

I know that SQL Server 2012 has the `lead` function which would make this question moot but how do I do that on sql server 2008?

Comment: Clarification: SQL Server 8 == SQL Server 2000. SQL Server 12 == SQL Server 2014. Reference: https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.be/. People usually do not refer to the build version of SQL Server but by the product name (ie SQL Server 2000, 2005, ..., 2016).

Comment: For an input set of {1,7,9,3}, do you want result {1-3, 3-7, 7-9} or {1-3, 7-9}?

Comment: Point taken. It's SQL SERVER 2008.  And yes i need the answer in {1-3,3-7,7-9}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #nr(nr INT); INSERT INTO #nr(nr)VALUES(9),(7),(1),(2),(25),(33),(10),(3);

SELECT
    CAST(n_o.nr AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST((SELECT MIN(n_i.nr) FROM #nr AS n_i WHERE n_i.nr>n_o.nr) AS VARCHAR)
FROM
    #nr AS n_o
WHERE
    (SELECT MIN(n_i.nr) FROM #nr AS n_i WHERE n_i.nr>n_o.nr) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    nr;

DROP TABLE #nr;
```

Results in:

```
╔══════════════════╗
║ (No column name) ║
╠══════════════════╣
║ 1-2              ║
║ 2-3              ║
║ 3-7              ║
║ 7-9              ║
║ 9-10             ║
║ 10-25            ║
║ 25-33            ║
╚══════════════════╝
```